# Zeros of a continuously differentiable function

Tags: analysis

Let $f: D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function defined on a domain $D$. Is it true that if $x$ is a non critical point of $f$, then there is a neighborhood of $x$ which contains no accumulation point of the set of zeros of $f$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)\ne0$, then there is a neighborhood of $x_0$ with no zeros of $f$. Without loss of generality, asume $f\colon(-a,a)\to\Bbb R$, $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)\ne0$. Then
$$
f(x)=f'(0)\,x+h(x)\quad\text{with}\quad \lim_{x\to0}\frac{h(x)}{x}=0.
$$
There exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$
|x|<\delta\implies\Bigl|\frac{h(x)}{x}\Bigr|\le\frac{|f'(0)|}{2}.
$$
Then, if $0<|x|<\delta$,
$$
|f(x)|\ge|f'(0)|\,|x|-|h(x)|\ge|f'(0)|\,|x|-\frac{|f'(0)|}{2}\,|x|\ge\frac{|f'(0)|}{2}\,|x|>0.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the statement true when $D$ is a domain in $R^n$?

Comment: No. Consider $f(x,y)=x$. Then $(0,0)$ is not a critical point, but $f(0,y)=0$ for all $y$.

Comment: you’re right. Thanks!